# What does the Riddler service do in the Fluid Framework reference service?

Tags: fluid-framework

The Riddler service does not have explicit documentation at the [package level](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/server/routerlicious/packages/routerlicious-base/src/riddler) and is not addressed in the Routerlicious service.

There is some code level documentation

> Riddler manages the tenants and then gives them to server for Alfred and Historian.

How should I be thinking about Riddler? Especially in relation to Alfred and Historian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riddler manages Tenants. In Routerlicious a tenant is a secret key & unique identifier pair. A tenant is usually a company or user group. The secret key is used to sign JWT tokens and the unique identifier identifies the tenant.

For example, during a hackathon we would give each hackathon team a different tenant. If we had a production service, we would give each company a different tenant.

Riddler lets you create and manage these tenants in Routerlicious.

In contrast, Historian and Alfred consume this tenant information. Historian and Alfred are not responsible for creating new tenants (new secret key, unique identifier pairs).

Comment: Thanks,But I'm still confused.
I have three ideas,
1. Historian was needed by Alfred and Riddler,Or the basis of fluid
2.Alfred is the gateway for clients to access servers,

Comment: But the relationship between Riddler and Alfred makes me wonder; they seem to be equals.
They are both do some with Tenants .

Comment: But sometimes I think they're not equals. it seem that Alfred is do some with Tenants through Riddler.

Comment: Updated to add clarity to the difference between these services